# How would you dynamically order an <option select> list using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I have a dropdown and a listbox, is there a way to order the listbox based on the dropdown using JQuery?  An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alters the order in the pulldown. You'll have to set the order depending on your own criteria:

```
<select id="the-select">
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(function (){
        $("#the-select option[value=2]").insertBefore("#the-select option[value=1]");
    });
//]]>
</script>
```