# moving select options up and down via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

so I got this code working for Firefox and Chrome...what it does is it allows you to reorder the options within an HTML select form...but then when I tested the code via IE8, it's kind of patchy...it only works for the first few clicks and after that you have to click many times on the button for it to work..

Does anybody know any other code that allows you to reorder select field items that works perfectly in IE8?

```
<select id="list" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="wtf">bahaha</option>
        <option value="meh">mwaahaha</option>

</select>
<button id="mup">Move Up</button>
<button id="mdown">Move Down</button>
<a href="#">Add Item</a>
<a href="#">Remove item</a>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#mup').click(function(){

  moveUpItem();

 });

 $('#mdown').click(function(){

  moveDownItem();

 });


});

 function moveUpItem(){
  $('#list option:selected').each(function(){
   $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
  });
 }

 function moveDownItem(){

  $('#list option:selected').each(function(){
   $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());
  });

 }
```

Comment: Not really related to your question, but you can improve your `moveDownItem()` function to safely handle a select box that allows for multiple selections by simply reversing the options before the `each()`, so like `$($('#list option:selected').get().reverse()).each(function(){ // etc.. }`

Comment: Nicely spotted @MickByrne

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code for changing the options works fine. It seems IE8 isn't handling a "fast" second-click with the `click` event but rather expects a `double click` to be handled.

Using my test code below, you'll notice that in IE8 writes out the following when `Move Down/Up` is pressed "fast":

```
Move Down Click
Move Down Double-Click
Move Down Click
Move Down Double-Click
```

But with FF/Chrome the following is printed:

```
Move Down Click
Move Down Click
Move Down Double-Click
Move Down Click
Move Down Click
Move Down Double-Click
```

Here's the code I'm using to test. I haven't done any tests to see if it's jQuery's event binders that are causing the issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<select id="list" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<button id="mup">Move Up</button>
<button id="mdown">Move Down</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

var $DEBUG = null;

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $DEBUG = $("#debug");

    $DEBUG.append("Registering Events<br />");

    $("#mup").click(moveUpItem);
    $("#mdown").click(moveDownItem);
    $("#mup").bind("dblclick", function ()
    {
        $DEBUG.append("Move Up Double-Click<br />");
    });
    $("#mdown").bind("dblclick", function ()
    {
        $DEBUG.append("Move Down Double-Click<br />");
    });

});

function moveUpItem()
{
    $DEBUG.append("Move Up Click<br />");
}

function moveDownItem()
{
    $DEBUG.append("Move Down Click<br />");
} 

 </script>

 <div id="debug" style="border: 1px solid red">
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:** I can confirm *it is* IE8 that is the problem. Swap this IE8-specific code in the $(document).ready() handler:

```
// $("#mup").click(moveUpItem);
$("#mup")[0].attachEvent("onclick", moveUpItem);
// $("#mdown").click(moveDownItem);
$("#mdown")[0].attachEvent("onclick", moveUpItem);
// $("#mup").bind("dblclick", function ()
$("#mup")[0].attachEvent("ondblclick", function ()
{
    $DEBUG.append("Move Up Double-Click<br />");
});
// $("#mdown").bind("dblclick", function ()
$("#mdown")[0].attachEvent("ondblclick", function ()
{
    $DEBUG.append("Move Down Double-Click<br />");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Example:
to move 3rd option before 1st option, we can use below jquery:

```
$('select[name="NameOfDropDown"] option:eq(2)').insertBefore($('select[name="NameOfDropDown"] option:eq(0)'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give some ideas of how to do it, you can dynamically place any option before one known position just by knowing the values of both, the one to move and the one of the position:

[How would you dynamically order an <option select> list using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660572/how-would-you-dynamically-order-an-option-select-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I know this one is a bit old, but I recently made this simple jQuery plugin to be able to reorder elements in a multiple select element.

Have a look and see if it helps for you, I tested in IE8,IE9,Chrome,FireFox,Opera.

http://fedegiust.github.io/selectReorder/